# use pygame to create animation of an enlarged radius of circle failed

Tags: python, pygame

i want to use python to create an animation of an enlarged raidus of a circle.
i use two ways to accomplish this, one way is success, the another is failed.
i want to know why, is there anyone can help.

version 1:

```
import pygame
global DISPLAYSURF, FPSCLOCK
pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWNWIDTH, WINDOWNHEIGHT))
radius = 1
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    radius = radius + 1
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (100, 100), radius)
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(1)
```

version2:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWNWIDTH, WINDOWNHEIGHT))

for radius in range(0, 100, 2):
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (100, 100), radius)
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(1)
while True:
   just_wait = True
```

the version is what i want , the version2 can not work

i run the code on macOs 10.13.1 High Sierra with python3 , why!!!

Comment: you have wrong indentions - use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: probably you put code with wrong indentions but I think in second version you run `while True` inside `for` loop - but `while True` is endless loop - you  never leave it - so you never go back to change circle and redraw it..

Comment: BTW: you can put `print(some-text)` in few places in code and you will see which part is executed - and you will see why it doen't  work.

Comment: thank you for help, i have run the code on my computer, there is no indention error, the  `while True` code just use to let the pygame window exists. i just curious about why the verison2 can not update the pygame windown, while the version1 is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you put code with wrong indentions and it should be

```
for radius in range(0, 100, 2):
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (100, 100), radius)
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(1)
    while True:
       just_wait = True
```

And it means you run `while True` loop inside `for` loop.

But `while True` loop is endless loop - you never leave it.
So it never go back to draw new circle and update screen.

You can put `print()` in code and you will see it.

---

First version is preferred version because it not only draw animation but it checks events so you can leave program in any time.

On some systems if you will not use `pygame.event.get():` to get events from system then system will think that program hung up and system can kill program.

Comment: thank you for help, i have run code on my computer. there is no indention error, the while True code just use to let the pygame window exists. i just curious about why the verison2 can not update the pygame windown, while the version1 is OK.

Comment: do you run version 2 with indentions like in my answer ? There is no indentions error in both but my version stops `for` loop and it can't update image. Your version should work so I assumed that there have to be indentions like in my version. It can be other problem - it doesn't get events from system and maybe it can't stops update on some systems. I didn't check it on my Linux.